# Getter/Setter for class variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Can getter/setter be auto-generated/enabled for class variables like that are being generated for instance variables using `attr_accessor`:

```
class School
  @@syllabus = :cbse

  def self.syllabus
    @@syllabus
  end

  def self.syllabus=(_)
    @@syllabus = _
  end
end

School.syllabus = :icse
School.syllabus # => :icse
```

Comment: No from Ruby core. But you can use [meta-programming power](http://stackoverflow.com/a/142378/2767755).

Comment: Thanks for confirming; I was unable to find an `attr_accessor` equivalent for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is to declare the `attr_accessor` in the scope of the class:

```
class School
 class << self
   attr_accessor :syllabus
  end
end

School.syllabus = :icse
School.syllabus # => :icse
```

Be aware though that the underlying member *will not* be `@@syllabus` (there is no built in solution for these kind of variables) but `@syllabus` in the class scope, which is the recommended way to do it anyway, see [this](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) blog post on the difference between the two:

> The issue with class variables is inheritance. Let’s say I want to subclass Polygon with Triangle like so:
>
> ```
> class Triangle < Polygon
>   @@sides = 3
> end
>
> puts Triangle.sides # => 3
> puts Polygon.sides # => 3
> ```
>
> Wha? But Polygon’s sides was set to 10? When you set a class variable, you set it for the superclass and all of the subclasses.

Comment: That's still _instnace var_... Not _class var_ :) AFAIK.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - what do you mean _instance_ var? it is a _class_ var, but not a _global_ var. Try it and see

Comment: I did not down vote.. Firstly :(... `@@x` is class var, where as `@x` is instance var.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable --- One related answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5890199/1120015 - another, see especially " it's a common idiom in Ruby to track class-level data with an instance variable on the class itself" @ArupRakshit

Comment: I think @Arup is just pointing out that `@syllabus` is a class instance variable: `School.instance_variables => [:@syllabus]`. You know that, of course.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - yes, I've understood that, and pointed to the difference in the answer itself

Comment: @UriAgassi Thanks! But I think clarifying that class variables doesn't have a getter/setter method would make your answer complete.

Comment: @UriAgassi The question does specifically ask for class variables,  as in `@@variable`, rather than class-level instance variables. Regarding "What do you mean instance var? It is a class var." - Well, it is an instance variable that belongs to the class (in this case `School`), just how instance variables normally belong to instances of a class (in this case instances of `School`). Class variables are a distinct concept, hence why we have a different syntax for them.

Comment: @JikkuJose - added the clarification

Comment: @UriAgassi thanks! You are a great contributor, have learnt a lot from your answers..

Answer (score 3):

Uri Agassi's answer is for setting instance variables on the class itself, something similar to, but not the same as class variables. See [Difference between class variables and class instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802540/difference-between-class-variables-and-class-instance-variables) for an explantation of the differences.

What you're looking for is something like rails' `cattr_accessor`. You can achieve that with a bit of meta-programming

```
module CattrAccessors
  def cattr_accessor(*attrs)
    cattr_reader(*attrs)
    cattr_writer(*attrs)
  end

  def cattr_reader(*attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr|
      define_singleton_method(attr) { class_variable_get("@@#{attr}") }
    end
  end

  def cattr_writer(*attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr|
      define_singleton_method("#{attr}=") { |value| class_variable_set("@@#{attr}", value) }
    end
  end
end
```

Then use it like so:

```
class School
  extend CattrAccessors

  attr_accessor :syllabus
end
```

I haven't tested the above module, so it may not work. Let me know if it does not.